# Endorement Error while invoking chain code

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I have a hyperledger fabric network setup in multiple servers and I successfully installed chaincode in different peers(`peer0.org1.com` and `peer0.org2.com`) of different organizations.

When I call the chaincode with putState(key,value) from `peer0.org1.com` I am able to commit the change but when I call the same chaincode from `peer0.org2.com` putstate(key, value) is failing with endorsement error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because you didn't include `peer0.org2.com` in the endorsement policy while installing the chaincode.
Ex: Include OR/AND ('ORG1MSP.member','ORG2MSP.member') in chaincode installation step

I hope this solves the issue